# where to place next/font inside nx workspace

Tags: next.js, material-ui, nrwl-nx

i have a NX workspace with nextjs and a few libraries. im using mui as the component library. im also using @next/font to load a google font.

I have created a library for the mui theme, i which i export a singel theme i want to use across entire application. there is no problem with the theme except for the font part. i did it exactly like this, https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript/src/theme.ts this example comes from the miu repo. i get the following error:

```
Font loaders cannot be used from within node_modules.
Location: ..\..\libs\shared\ui\src\lib\shared-ui.tsx
```

this is my project.json for the nx workspace

```
{
  "name": "shared-ui",
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/shared/ui/src",
  **"projectType": "library",**
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/shared/ui/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "libs/shared/ui/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as u can see it is a lib.
how can i use the next/font with mui inside a NX workspace?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with similar setup (themes coming from a shared ui Nx lib). I worked around it by passing in the font as a parameter under /apps to the theme provider component under /libs. I guess Next needs the font loader to be called in the app itself to do its magic.

```
import { Roboto } from '@next/font/google';
import { CustomThemeProvider } from '@shared-ui';
...
const roboto = Roboto({...});
...
<CustomThemeProvider fontFamily={roboto.style.fontFamily}>{children}</CustomThemeProvider>
```