# Cannot find next/google/font module in Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl

#### Import Syntax Unclear For Types

The docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization) show

`import { <font-name> } from 'next/google/font';`

It compiles but at run-time throws the error "module not found".

[image: Screenshot 2023-04-13 at 07 45 38]

But [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44225) discussion shows:

`import { <font-name> } from '@next/google/font';`

This version throws this error at compile time.

[image]

It would help to at least know whether the "@" is required or not. I hope the docs are up-to-date and the discussion is not. Neither error that is thrown helps to disambiguate these 2 syntaxes!

#### This is an nx mono-repo

Btw, this is in a NextJs project inside a nrwl nx mono-repo.

I tried updating the package.json to include:

```
"@types/next": "13.1.1",
```

but that did not help.

Note that the `package.json` is at the root of the monorepo (but all other deps and devDeps are there, so it must be the correct place, as sub-projects don't have their own package.json files).

#### Type Declaration File

Inside the app (ie. the sub-folder) is an `index.d.ts` file where I tried adding:

`declare module 'next/font/google'`

and

`declare module '@next/font/google'`

Neither solved the problem.

#### Stackoverlfow similar issue

There is [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951355/where-to-place-next-font-inside-nx-workspace), but that did not help either.

#### Yarn lock file

In the `yarn.lock` file is the following entry, which seems to package next inside the @nrwl namespace, so I tried '@nrwl/next/google/font' but that also did not work

```yaml
"@nrwl/next@15.8.8":
  version "15.8.8"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nrwl/next/-/next-15.8.8.tgz"
  integrity sha512-h7sYBf8ljyfXyoSCgiHxukB/AyZsHNL8g+vSVmr7iCkVd6IgFIa1n3myM7vaALAVrJ0EccXYdK7yuKHbVvfLnA==
  dependencies:
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators" "^7.14.5"
    "@nrwl/devkit" "15.8.8"
    "@nrwl/js" "15.8.8"
    "@nrwl/linter" "15.8.8"
    "@nrwl/react" "15.8.8"
    "@nrwl/workspace" "15.8.8"
    "@svgr/webpack" "^6.1.2"
    chalk "^4.1.0"
    copy-webpack-plugin "^10.2.4"
    dotenv "~10.0.0"
    express "^4.18.1"
    fs-extra "^11.1.0"
    http-proxy-middleware "^2.0.6"
    ignore "^5.0.4"
    semver "7.3.4"
    ts-node "10.9.1"
    tsconfig-paths "^4.1.2"
    tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin "4.0.0"
    url-loader "^4.1.1"
    webpack-merge "^5.8.0"
```

Comment: What is your Next.js version? not @types/next

Comment: @zer0321 13.1.1 Just learned that next/font is a totally separate package! doh! Posted the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Before Next.js 13.2.0**

- You need to add package @next/font
  `yarn add @next/font` /or/ `npm i @next/font`

**After Next.js 13.2.0** (Next.js 13.2.0 and higher)

- Next fonts package is included to Next.js by default, so you don't need to install extra package (if you have @next/font installed, remove it) and you need to import from the native package `next/font` instead of `@next/font` (without the `@`)

Comment: Juan pointed out its actually 13.2.0 where next fonts are included. I'm on 13.0.5 so I need to add the @next/font@13.0.5 package. It wouldn't work with latest @next/font so I had to match my version of next with @next/font

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you will need to ensure that your Next.js version is above 13.2.0. Prior to this version, you will need to install the @next/font package, as explained in the Next.js YouTube video in the docs:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8_98i_bMMA

You can find more information about the version changes and the new feature added in the following link:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/font#version-changes